# SSH connection on remote machine using robot framework: Channel Exception;(4,Resource Shortage")

Tags: python-2.7, testing, ssh, robotframework

I am trying to establish an SSH connection to a remote machine using robot framework and execute some commands. But I get an error saying ChannelException:(4,'Resource shortage') and I have no idea what it means.

```
Script: test.robot
*** Settings ***
Library    SSHLibrary
Suite Setup    open_connection_and_login
Suite Teardown    Close All Connections

*** Variables ***
${HOST}    login
${USERNAME}    root
${PASSWORD}    password

*** Test Cases ***
available_disk_on_remote
    ${output}=    Execute Command  df -h
    Log To Console    "${output}"

*** Keywords ***
open_connection_and_login
    Open Connection    ${HOST}
    Login  ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}   4

Output:
[root@machine1 Robot]# robot test.robot
===========================================================================
Test
======================================================================
available_disk_on_remote                                             | FAIL |
ChannelException: (4, 'Resource shortage')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test                                                                 | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
=========================================================================
Output:  /root/Robot/output.xml
Log:     /root/Robot/log.html
Report:  /root/Robot/report.html
```

Python 2.7.5 and Robot Framework 3.0.2 
(FYI, new to Robot Framework)

Comment: Any chance the target is cisco-ish switch? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Run and Return RC and Output from OperatingSystem library to achieve this . Please find working code below.

```
*** Settings ***
Library                OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
 Check disk usage
    ${rc}      ${output} =     Run And Return Rc And Output     df -h
    Should Be Equal As Integers        ${rc}           0
    Log to console      ${output}
```

This will give you following output

```
[root@scripts]# pybot  diskusage.robot
==============================================================================
Diskusage                                                                     
==============================================================================
Check disk usage                                                      ..Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_tv274-lv_root
                       47G   20G   25G  44% /
tmpfs                 4.9G   84K  4.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   38M  423M   9% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_tv274-lv_home
                      4.6G  138M  4.2G   4% /home
/dev/sr0              658M  658M     0 100% /media/Ubuntu-Server 12.04.1 LTS amd64
Check disk usage                                                      | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Diskusage                                                             | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

1. SSH, also known as Secure Shell or Secure Socket Shell, is a network protocol that gives users, particularly system administrators, a secure way to access a computer over an unsecured network. SSH also refers to the suite of utilities that implement the SSH protocol. Secure Shell provides strong authentication and encrypted data communications between two computers connecting over an open network such as the internet. SSH is widely used by network administrators for managing systems and applications remotely, allowing them to log into another computer over a network, execute commands and move files from one computer to another.
2. Sshlibrary is used to connect SSH client
3. To install sshlibrary execute command in command prompt

   - pip install robotframework-sshlibrary
4. import sshlibrary in robot framework
5. Sample Robot Framework code to connect ssh and download file from server.

   Open    Connection    ${Host}
   Login    ${Username}    ${pwd}
   sshLibrary.Directory    Should Exist    /ug05/abc/src/rpa
   ${XML_FILE} sshlibrary.Get File /ug05/abc/src/rpa/*.xml
   Close    Connection